# Where does ant's "modified" selector write its cache by default?

Tags: ant

I want to debug some behavior with the "modified" selector in Ant 1.8.2.

[This page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#modified) describes tons of junk, but not where it stores its cache.  Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that the default cache is "propertyfile". It also states that the default name for the cachefile is **cache.properties**.

Finally it also supplies an example that outlines all the default settings, demonstrating how these can be changed.

```
<copy todir="dest">
    <fileset dir="src">
        <modified update="true"
                  seldirs="true"
                  cache="propertyfile"
                  algorithm="digest"
                  comparator="equal">
            <param name="cache.cachefile"     value="cache.properties"/>
            <param name="algorithm.algorithm" value="MD5"/>
        </modified>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Ah, "cache.properties". I missed that.  Thanks!